# C++: Comparing sets of points in a data file

Tags: c++

I have a data file consisting of three columns, x, y, and z (these are numbers). I'd like to do the following:

1. Compare each (x, y) set in the data.
2. If two sets are equal, say (x1, y1) = (x2, y2),
3. Then, compare z1 and z2. And depending on the comparison, I'll write a condition and I want to overwrite one of the sets such that it takes the value of the one that pass some conditions I make.

The data contains thousands of points, so I'm not sure how to do the comparison effectively, and how to overwrite or omit the point that doesn't pass that conditions.

> So can someone please suggest something, or give a small
>   example for the case where I have only two points (x1, y1, z1) and (x2, y2, z2).

Comment: Are these integer `x1`, `y1` or floating point values?

Comment: Just _thousands_?? No problem, load everything into the memory, filter and store back.

Comment: they are floating point values.

Comment: @Vlad I don't understand. Can you elaborate please.

Comment: Well. Declare a structure containing 3 doubles (x, y, and z). Load an array of such structs from the file. Compare the structs and remove the ones you don't need from the array. Store the array back to the file. (For C++, array = `std::vector`.) Does any of the parts look complicated?

Comment: @Vlad Okay, sounds promising except that I haven't dealt with arrays before. So, I'll go read and try my best. Maybe I'll ask for some hints later. Thanks.

Comment: Well, with `std::vector` you need (1) `push_back` for adding items, (2) item access with `[]`, (3) erasing the items from the middle with `v.erase(v.begin() + index)`.

Comment: You're welcome, I had to show your answer to a friend who knows C++, he helped me write a small code that does what I need. So thanks and thanks for the +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to compare all the points with all the the other points, you can do an algorithm like the following. Assume a data structures like this:

```
struct Data {
    double x_, y_, z_;
    bool skip;
    const std::pair<double, double> & xy () const {
        return std::pair<double, double>(x, y);
    }
};

std::vector<Data> file;
typedef std::multimap<std::pair<double, double>, unsigned> PointMap;
PointMap xyline;
```

Then when you read in the file, you search the `xyline` to see if the current point already exists or not. If so, update the current point and the `file` vector accordingly (since you know the line numbers of all the matching points, you can modify all matches or only the latest one, your choice). Then insert the current point associated with the current line, and then iterate to the next line in the file.

After the file is processed, write out the contents of `file`. Then, you can use the output to replace the existing file if you so choose.

```
void update (PointMap::iterator first, PointMap::iterator last, Data &d) {
    //... revisit all matching points and decide which to keep
}

Data d;
std::ifstream ifile;
std::ofstream ofile;
ifile.open("input.dat");
while (ifile >> d.x_ >> d.y_ >> d.z_) {
    PointMap::iterator i = xyline.find(d.xy());
    if (i != xyline.end()) {
        update(i, xyline.upper_bound(d.xy(), d);
    }
    xyline.insert(i, std::pair<d.xy(), file.size());
    file.push_back(d);
}

ofile.open("output.dat");
for (size_t i = 0; i < file.size(); ++i) {
    d = file[i];
    if (!d.skip)
        ofile << d.x_ << " " << d.y_ << " " << d.z_ << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef std::map<float, float> Leafs;
typedef std::map<float, Leafs> Node;

Node root;
```

populate tree in this way:
let's say you want to add (a,b,c)

```
Leafs l;
l[ b ] = c;
root[ a ] = l;
```

then when you add new value use **find** (check std::map::find method description) method to check if value exists. This should be fast enough solution of this 'problem'